# CSS: Prevent <picture> element from extending outside grid item set to 1:1 aspect ratio

Tags: css

I am trying to prevent an image from extending outside the border of a grid item that has a height set of 0 and padding-top of 100% to maintain a 1:1 aspect ratio. It works fine when using an `<img>` element (on the left), but not a `<picture>` element (on the right).

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr
}

.item {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(20px, 1fr) auto auto minmax(20px, 1fr);
}

.text {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.img {
  grid-row-start: 3;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid">
  <li class="item">
    <div class="inner">
      <p class="text">Text</p>
      <img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1621250755294-57cf625b4a9a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="inner">
      <p class="text">Text</p>
      <picture class="img">
        <source srcset="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1621250755294-57cf625b4a9a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80 1x, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1618236507249-9960f2c6a53d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80 2x"
          media="(min-width: 360px)">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1621250755294-57cf625b4a9a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80" />
      </picture>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: add also max-width:100% to the image inside the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a class to the img as well.

```
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1621250755294-57cf625b4a9a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80" />
```

to

```
<img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1621250755294-57cf625b4a9a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80" />
```

Add overflow: auto to class `img`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mecp5rL0/)

Comment: Also, just realized both overflow in edge and chrome.

Comment: @JordanCarter Would this work for you? https://jsfiddle.net/mecp5rL0/

Comment: That works. What did you do differently? Works on Edge too

Comment: I put it on the  answer a while ago. I used `overflow: auto` @JordanCarter

Comment: I wish. I was expecting the image to be cut when I put that in and add some more properties, but it just fixed it somehow. xD

Comment: I think the trick is to apply the .img css to the picture img element, and apply overflow auto to the picture element. https://jsfiddle.net/3fxp5Lwo/